# IFeatureDataset.CreateFeatureClass Error

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-9.3, .net

I'm working on a webservice in ArcObjects 9.3. 
It works fine when deployed on IIS, but when I try to debug some unit tests I keep getting the same error:

> The remote procedure call failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BE)

The error occurs when calling the CreateFeatureClass(..) method throught the IDataset interface.

```
public void CreateOutputFeatureClass(string featureClassName)
    {
        var masterFeatureClass = Helpers.GetMaster(Session, ServerContext);
        IFeatureClassDescription fcDesc = new FeatureClassDescriptionClass();
        var ocDesc = (IObjectClassDescription)fcDesc;
        var featureDataset = featureWorkspace.OpenFeatureDataset(Session.Dataset);
        featureDataset.CreateFeatureClass(featureClassName, masterFeatureClass.Fields, ocDesc.InstanceCLSID,
            ocDesc.ClassExtensionCLSID, esriFeatureType.esriFTSimple, masterFeatureClass.ShapeFieldName, "");            
    }
```

Based on other posts I have been reading about this error this has something to do with user permission, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by this line of code:

```
IFeatureClassDescription fcDesc = new FeatureClassDescriptionClass();
```

I should have created that object within the ServerContext. In my code sample above I created the feature class description outside the serverContext and used it to create a feature class in a feature dataset that was created within the serverContext. This conflicted and was perceived as a remote procedure (cfr. Error message).